# HP iLO2 and IPv6

Tags: ipv6, ilo

Does anyone know if the HP iLO2 controller has support for IPv6 as its interface address?

I have seen something about the iLO3 controllers supporting IPv6 but I am unable to find anything talking about the iLO2.

I am running the current firmware v2.12, My actual server platform is an HP Proliant DL360 G5.

Answer (score 4):

iLO 2 supports [IPv4 only](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1146658&swItem=MTX-ab90093287a14896b02f537b7b&prodNameId=1135772&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=5). (Note that [2.12 was a security and bugfix release](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1146658&swItem=MTX-d93f87ad5c9f4c94b4901ff9d6&prodNameId=1135772&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=2) only, and added no new features.)

For IPv6 support, you need [iLO 3, firmware revision 1.50 or higher](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=4154735&swItem=MTX-eafb4350072f4be7ab6ecc695f&prodNameId=4154847&swEnvOID=4040&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=5), or [iLO 4](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c03334058/c03334058.pdf) (any firmware release).

Comment: Sigh.... Ok well I need to find other options then. Thanks for the information.